# How to do basic visible with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I want to make one page with static html using sf2. First time using knockout.js and I'm stuck at the very first thing :(

I want to show main content (later add animation) with click from the navigation. I've done the single page tutorial 3 times and it's not helping, I'm not understanding something.

Anyway, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LXCCA/) with html extracted. What must I refactor: my setPage gets run and I think it should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your methodology is incorrect.  Have a look at this jsfiddle and see what you think.

http://jsfiddle.net/7xqjY/

I've edited it quite heavily but I hope that you can see where you were going wrong

FYI, your setPage was executing because when knockout parses the bindings, it executes the function (in your case to determine whether the element is visible)

Comment: I was trying to avoid making the pages an array, I wanted to load everything with sf2 twig includes, and not use ajax now. Also, the navigation has subtext, so now I need to make the array not string but objects to hold multiple values? Also, I'm still not getting why setPage runs, it's bound to click, and not visible according to my understanding. Thanks for answering.

Comment: I didn't know what sf2 was and google didn't bring up anything so I thought I would show a solution that was framework agnostic.  The array isn't strings by the way, they are fully fledged objects with a "name" property

Comment: I've edited your script to show you why the `setPage` was executed and how to prevent it (wrap it in a `function(){}`): http://jsfiddle.net/soniiic/LXCCA/2/

Comment: Thank you continual assistance. I think I realised the crux of the problem of my misunderstanding: I don't have a model. That's why what I needed can be done with basic jQuery, and forgot that knockoutjs is complementary. It makes sense how the first thing you did was to make the pages the 'model'. So to use ko I 'must' have a model and that will be my pages for this. I'm going to do some big refactoring, but hopefully with more knowledge and less confusion :)